# Config setting for Linux kernel compilation

Tags: kernel, configuration, kernel-modules

I need a Linux kernel compiled with debug features for a kernel module development.What all debugging configuration options should I include for kernel compilation,So that I can avail to all available debug tools.

Also, I am thinking about including all available debug facilities in kernel, like including whole of the "Kernel Hacking" configuration branch into the kernel.Will there's any side effect to it, in terms of: final build size and performance penalty etc.

Comment: **Q:** How do I get all the options? **A:** Answer Y to all the configure options. *Wait could you repeat the question I must have missed something :)*

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are side effects in terms of build size and performance. However, you are doing a debug build! They aren't huge and some can be modules that you only load when you're using them, but still you aren't going to be using it for your high performance production server.

Beyond that there doesn't seem to be anything to answer in your question. If you know what tools you want to avail yourself of, it should be clear which options to enable to get the tools to work. If you are asking about what software to use to debug the kernel, that's a different question, and you should figure out exactly what you want to ask and ask that question.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I am new to module development. I just wanted to confirm that by including "Kernel Hacking" am I including all debug facilities or there are something more somewhere. I don't know any thing about debug tools requirement, but I want to make sure that I don't have to recompile it again for another debug tool to work.

Comment: If you are doing kernel debug work get used to recompiling the kernel! The best thing to do would be to automate the process so that any changes require as little effort from you as possible. Of course modules can be compiled without rebuilding the whole kernel, but you'll find you'll want to do this anyway now and then. Reasons come up. I can build a new kernel in a few seconds with a couple keys using script that does everything from finding and downloading the latest version, matching my current config, allowing me to make any config changes, compiling, installing, editing my boot loader.